# Basic level linking leaflet to a database - recreating CoffeeShop example

Tags: php, mysql, leaflet

I am trying to work through the example [from Chapter 5 of the Leaflet.js succinctly book](http://ebooks.syncfusion.com/downloads/Leafletjs_Succinctly/Leafletjs_Succinctly.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ5W3G2Z6F2ZHAREQ&Expires=1536651989&Signature=Cpgkf%2Fby590q0hETeD3HcAe1uhg%3D) - but cannot get any of the coffee shops to show on my map.

Some of the commands give me errors so I've looked for workarounds, and I suspect the problem could be as simple as files not being in the correct place.  Is there an idiot's guide to using databases with leaflet I could follow? Or can someone see the error I am making?

My set up:

- using XAMPP on a Mac - the MySQL Database and Apache Web Server are running
- I created the leafletDB database using the terminal
  `/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/mysql -u root -p`
  `create database leafletDB`
- I filled the database by copy paste into the terminal the contents of the CoffeeShops.sql file (I could not get the from CSV command  `mysql –uroot –pleaflet < "C:\CoffeeShops.sql";` to work, even changing the path to CoffeeShops.sql)
- Checking the database using `USE leafletDB;` `SHOW TABLES;` and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM coffeeshops;` all gave the expected results.
- The leaflet database is located in `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/`
- I copied the coffee.php file to the `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/CoffeeExample` folder, which is the same file as the listing43.html file (the file that creates the map)
- The only change I made to the listing43.html file was the path to the mugIcon (put in the same folder).  I also tried simply removing the icon command - it made no difference.

The map displays, any markers coded directly into the html file display - but nothing from the database.

What have I got wrong?

As requested here is a copy of all the code - sorry for how long this is

*listing43.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>My Leaflet.js Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js">
    </script>
    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            var map = L.map('map').setView([42.362, -71.085], 13);

            // OSM Mapnik
            var osmLink = "<a href='http://www.openstreetmap.org'>Open StreetMap</a>";
            L.tileLayer(
                'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    attribution: '&copy; ' + osmLink,
                    maxZoom: 18
                }).addTo(map);

            showCoffeeShops(map);

            L.marker([42.362,-71.085]).addTo(map)
                .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
                .openPopup();

        }

        function showCoffeeShops(map) {

            var mugIcon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: "mug.png",
                iconSize: [25,25]
            });
            $.getJSON("coffee.php", function(data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].Latitude, data[i].Longitude);
                    var name = data[i].Name;
                    var addr1 = data[i].Address1;
                    if(data[i].Address2.length > 1) {
                        addr2 = data[i].Address2 + "</br>";
                    } else {
                        addr2 = "";
                    }
                    var cityzip = data[i].City + ", " + data[i].Zip;
                    var visits = data[i].Visits;

                    var marker = new L.Marker(location, {
                        icon: mugIcon,
                        title: name
                    });
                    var content = "<h2>" + name + "</h2>"
                        + "<p>" + addr1 + "</br>" + addr2
                        + cityzip + "</p>"
                        + "<p>Visits: <b>" + visits + "</b></p>";

                    marker.bindPopup(content, {
                        maxWidth: '200'
                    });
                    marker.addTo(map);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

*coffee.php*

```
<?php
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=leafletDB", "root", "leaflet");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM CoffeeShops WHERE City='Boston'";
    $rs = $db->query($sql);
    if (!$rs) {
        echo "An SQL error occured.\n";
        exit;
    }
    $rows = array();
    while($r = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
    $db = NULL;
?>
```

*CoffeeShops.sql* (note this has been truncated, there are a few thousand lines in the database)

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.4.14
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Nov 24, 2015 at 05:56 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.26
-- PHP Version: 5.6.12

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `leafletDB`
--

USE leafletDB;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `CoffeeShops`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CoffeeShops`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coffeeshops` (
  `StoreID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Telephone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Address1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `State` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `Zipcode` char(9) NOT NULL,
  `Latitude` decimal(9,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Longitude` decimal(9,6) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Truncate table before insert `CoffeeShops`
--

TRUNCATE TABLE `CoffeeShops`;
--
-- Dumping data for table `CoffeeShops`
--

INSERT INTO `CoffeeShops` (`StoreID`, `Name`, `Telephone`, `Address1`, `Address2`, `City`, `State`, `Zipcode`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`) VALUES
(11854, 'Epping Main St', '603-679-8789', '96 Calef Highway', '', 'Epping', 'NH', '03042-222', '43.031873', '-71.073203'),
(79420, 'Stop & Shop-Exeter #204', '603-772-1783', '139 Portsmouth Ave', '', 'Exeter', 'NH', '03833-210', '42.989763', '-70.932044'),
(3872, 'Target Greenland T-2530', '603-501-1470', '1450 Greenland Rd', '', 'Greenland', 'NH', '03840-243', '43.048710', '-70.816345'),
(13448, 'Seabrook, Lafayette Rd', '603-474-3674', '271 Lafayette Rd', '', 'Seabrook', 'NH', '03874-451', '42.882128', '-70.868080'),
(10325, 'Portsmouth, Woodbury Avenue', '603-436-1547', '1855 Woodbury Avenue', '', 'Portsmouth', 'NH', '03801-322', '43.092318', '-70.792327'),
(7459, 'Portsmouth/Market Square/Cigar Stor', '603-433-4471', '1 Market Square, Suite 17D', 'Suite 17D', 'Portsmouth', 'NH', '03801-401', '43.077086', '-70.758064'),
(11182, 'Haverhill, 1116 Main St', '978-372-3485', '1116 Main Street', '', 'Haverhill', 'MA', '01830-141', '42.807206', '-71.102071'),
(7329, 'Newburyport', '978-462-4475', '23 Market Square', '', 'Newburyport', 'MA', '01950-257', '42.811138', '-70.869501'),
(7907, 'Kittery', '207-451-9701', '306 Highway 1, M150', 'M150', 'Kittery', 'ME', '3904', '43.111116', '-70.734091'),
(76864, 'Target Haverhill T-2325', '978-377-9003', '35 Computer Dr', '', 'Haverhill', 'MA', '01832-123', '42.786955', '-71.115836'),
(9991, 'Dover, NH', '603-742-1867', '11 Webb Place', '', 'Dover', 'NH', '03820-240', '43.221256', '-70.888115'),
(76677, 'Target - Somersworth T-2182', '603-692-6750', '11 Andrews Rd', '', 'Somersworth', 'NH', '03878-104', '43.232909', '-70.881800'),
(7570, 'Methuen/The Loop', '978-681-5284', '90 Pleasant Valley St, Unit 170', 'Unit 170', 'Methuen', 'MA', '01844-728', '42.744153', '-71.157345'),
(16926, 'Target Salem T-1186', '603-870-0071', '203 S Broadway', '', 'Salem', 'NH', '03079-337', '42.764387', '-71.216689'),
(76855, 'Target Methuen T-2287', '978-983-0013', '67 Pleasant Valley St', '', 'Methuen', 'MA', '01844-720', '42.741881', '-71.160069'),
(13411, 'Manchester, S. Willow St.', '603-641-4839', '1111 South Willow St', '', 'Manchester', 'NH', '03103-403', '42.960288', '-71.438445'),
(75663, 'MHT - Manchester Post Sec New Wng', '', '1 Airport Rd', '', 'Manchester', 'NH', '03103-745', '42.927098', '-71.446557'),
(76481, 'Target Bedford T-2009', '603-263-0061', '220 S River Rd', '', 'Bedford', 'NH', '03110-681', '42.943270', '-71.474100'),
(7773, 'N Andover/Rte 114', '978-975-7229', '562 Turnpike Street', '', 'North Andover', 'MA', '01845-581', '42.665865', '-71.115143'),
(885, 'Andover', '978-475-7752', '14 Main Street', '', 'Andover', 'MA', '01810-370', '42.656393', '-71.140289'),
(9716, 'Concord, Loudon Road', '603-223-2395', '240 Loudon Road', '', 'Concord', 'NH', '03301-602', '43.222904', '-71.491969'),
(7960, 'Nashua Mall Power Center', '603-579-4761', '10 Coliseum Avenue', '', 'Nashua', 'NH', '03063-323', '42.765130', '-71.497440'),
(7450, 'Beverly', '978-922-0885', '29 Enon Street', '', 'Beverly', 'MA', '01915-111', '42.585366', '-70.884440'),
(14996, 'UMASS - Lowell', '', '1 Solomont Way', '', 'Lowell', 'MA', '01854-512', '42.641549', '-71.334888'),
(10278, 'Pheasant Lane Mall', '603-897-1860', '310 Daniel Webster Hwy., E281', 'E281', 'Nashua', 'NH', '03060-573', '42.700708', '-71.436142'),
(11531, 'Nashua, 611 Amherst St', '603-883-1600', '611 Amherst St.', '', 'Nashua', 'NH', '03063-101', '42.801030', '-71.537014'),
(5107, 'Target Lowell T-2480', '978-703-2020', '199 Plain St', '', 'Lowell', 'MA', '01852-513', '42.624620', '-71.318450'),
(11848, 'Beverly, 242 Elliott St', '978-927-0748', '242 Elliott St.', '', 'Beverly', 'MA', '01915-241', '42.556249', '-70.890407'),
(7658, 'Chelmsford', '978-458-2464', '101 Drum Hill Road', '', 'Chelmsford', 'MA', '01824-151', '42.623739', '-71.364310'),
(833, 'Peabody', '978-531-8224', '240 Andover Street', '', 'Peabody', 'MA', '01960-153', '42.545939', '-70.946655'),
(2765, 'North Shore Mall', '978-531-1331', '210 Andover Street, Space W 133', '', 'Peabody', 'MA', '01960-167', '42.545240', '-70.944680'),
(11757, 'Wilmington Crossing', '978-658-2541', '271 Main St., Space #253', 'Space #253', 'Wilmington', 'MA', '01887-232', '42.555543', '-71.181095'),
(8650, 'Billerica', '978-436-9180', '199 Boston Road, Unit 15', 'Unit 15', 'Billerica', 'MA', '01862-232', '42.581632', '-71.289347'),
(9269, 'Reading Walkers Brook', '781-942-8290', '24 Walkers Brook Drive', '', 'Reading', 'MA', '01867-322', '42.519991', '-71.093858'),
(7356, 'Salem-Dodge Street', '978-825-0824', '211 Washington Street', '', 'Salem', 'MA', '01970-360', '42.518951', '-70.894874'),
(7772, 'Reading', '781-942-0168', '288 Main Street', '', 'Reading', 'MA', '01867-361', '42.515659', '-71.104029'),
(15489, 'Target Woburn T-1266', '781-904-0002', '101 Commerce Way', '', 'Woburn', 'MA', '01801-100', '42.518122', '-71.135588'),
(9984, 'Woburn, Commerce Way', '781-933-4672', '99 Commerce Way', '', 'Woburn', 'MA', '01801-519', '42.517323', '-71.135712'),
(75861, 'Maine Turnpike Kennebunk North', '207-985-4234', 'maine Trnpike Northbound exit 24', '', 'Kennebunk', 'ME', '04043-702', '43.385365', '-70.542110'),
(75860, 'Kennebunk South, Maine Turnpike', '207-985-4817', 'Maine Turnpike Southbound MM 24', '', 'kennebunk', 'ME', '04043-702', '43.385365', '-70.542110'),
(7812, 'Woburn, West Cummings Park', '781-938-9305', '200 W Cummings Park, 1', '1', 'Woburn', 'MA', '01801-633', '42.498180', '-71.125908'),
(7522, 'Marblehead', '781-639-0368', '89 Pleasant Street', '', 'Marblehead', 'MA', '01945-338', '42.502632', '-70.856048'),
(13978, 'Saugus, The Shops at Saugus', '781-231-4928', '366 B Broadway', '', 'Saugus', 'MA', '01906-190', '42.488116', '-71.019400'),
(802, 'Swampscot', '781-581-9001', '1016 Paradise Road', '', 'Swampscott', 'MA', '01907-135', '42.484973', '-70.901011'),
(7269, 'Saugus', '781-233-4173', '723 Broadway', '', 'Saugus', 'MA', '01906-320', '42.478313', '-71.023173'),
(9913, 'Westford Valley Marketplace', '978-392-5926', '174 Littleton Road', '', 'Westford', 'MA', '01886-319', '42.566563', '-71.421995'),
(7279, 'Marketplace at Burlington', '781-273-6544', '84 Burlington Mall Road, Suite D', 'Suite D', 'Burlington', 'MA', '01803-453', '42.487550', '-71.202290'),
(10598, 'Bedford, Great Road', '781-275-0992', '186 Great Road', '', 'Bedford', 'MA', '01730-271', '42.489622', '-71.272350'),
(7258, 'Melrose Center', '781-662-0217', '521 Main Street', '', 'Melrose', 'MA', '02176-383', '42.455468', '-71.064841'),
(876, 'Winchester', '781-729-1626', '542 Main Street', '', 'Winchester', 'MA', '01890-291', '42.452030', '-71.136821'),
(7553, 'Lexington/Bedford Rd', '781-863-1189', '60 Bedford Street', '', 'Lexington', 'MA', '02420-433', '42.453613', '-71.233316'),
(866, 'Lexington', '781-863-8485', '1729 Massachusetts Ave', '', 'Lexington', 'MA', '02420-530', '42.447500', '-71.226705'),
(76681, 'Target Biddeford T-2166', '207-284-2510', '585 Alfred Rd', '', 'Biddeford', 'ME', '4005', '43.474469', '-70.513594'),
(7283, 'Medford - Star Market', '781-396-3630', '2151 Mystic Valley Parkway', '', 'Medford', 'MA', '02155-375', '42.417173', '-71.126646'),
(7364, 'Mass. Ave., Arlington', '781-646-9366', '1465 Massachusetts Ave', '', 'Arlington', 'MA', '02476-410', '42.425296', '-71.188507'),
(7205, 'Arlington', '781-641-2893', '327 Broadway', '', 'Arlington', 'MA', '02474-530', '42.414751', '-71.150990'),
(8988, 'Station Landing', '781-395-0660', '5 Revere Beach Pkwy., Station Landing Phase 1', 'Station Landing Phase 1', 'Medford', 'MA', '02155-515', '42.404329', '-71.081279'),
(10037, 'Tilton, Tanger Outlet', '603-286-2640', '120 Laconia Road, Suite 100', '', 'Tilton', 'NH', '03276-523', '43.457104', '-71.563661'),
(76315, 'Target Revere T-1942', '781-922-6030', '36 Furlong Dr', '', 'Revere', 'MA', '02151-400', '42.400825', '-71.001876'),
(816, 'Concord', '978-287-0183', '159 Sudbury Road', '', 'Concord', 'MA', '01742-342', '42.455669', '-71.355854'),
(15208, 'Target Everett T-1229', '617-420-0000', '1 Mystic View Rd', '', 'Everett', 'MA', '02149-242', '42.401847', '-71.069932'),
(14138, 'East Boston', '617-561-3704', '430 McClellan Highway', '', 'East Boston', 'MA', '02128-114', '42.393203', '-71.012803'),
(78032, 'BOS Term B AA Pre-Security', '617-634-6097', '440 McClellan Highway', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02128-112', '42.393095', '-71.013054'),
(7502, 'Davis Square Plaza', '617-623-4497', '260 Elm Street', '', 'Somerville', 'MA', '02144-295', '42.395759', '-71.122297'),
(871, 'Belmont', '617-484-3213', '47 Leonard St.', '', 'Belmont', 'MA', '02478-252', '42.397256', '-71.175393'),
(7835, 'Acton, Kelly''s Corner', '978-264-1992', '411 Massachusettes Ave', '', 'Acton', 'MA', '01720-373', '42.474910', '-71.451609'),
(8873, 'Cambridge, Fresh Pond', '617-876-1070', '222 Alewife Brook Parkway', '', 'Cambridge', 'MA', '2138', '42.389322', '-71.141328'),
(2764, 'Somerville Avenue', '617-776-6783', '711-723 Somerville Ave', '', 'Somerville', 'MA', '02143-353', '42.386083', '-71.114181'),
(827, 'Shepard Post', '617-491-0442', '1662 Massachusetts Ave', '', 'Cambridge', 'MA', '02138-183', '42.381903', '-71.119934'),
(16917, 'Target Somerville T-1441', '617-766-4036', '180 Somerville Ave', '', 'Somerville', 'MA', '02143-340', '42.377651', '-71.090108'),
(75650, 'BOS - Terminal E - Food Court', '617-634-6097', 'Boston Logan Term E Food Court', '', 'East Boston', 'MA', '2128', '42.370131', '-71.019672'),
(810, 'Broadway Marketplace', '617-491-9911', '468 Broadway', '', 'Cambridge', 'MA', '02138-390', '42.373886', '-71.112950'),
(7241, '31 Church', '617-492-7870', '31 Church Street', '', 'Cambridge', 'MA', '02138-371', '42.374494', '-71.120170'),
(7538, 'Belmont/Cushing Sq', '617-489-8767', '112 Trapelo Rd', '', 'Belmont', 'MA', '02478-187', '42.380603', '-71.175129'),
(7102, 'Harvard Yard', '617-354-3726', '1380 Mass Ave', '', 'Cambridge', 'MA', '2138', '42.373456', '-71.119328'),
(861, 'Harvard Square', '617-492-4881', '36 JFK Street', '', 'Cambridge', 'MA', '02138-491', '42.372485', '-71.119452'),
(75840, 'BOS Boston/Logan Airport Term C', '617-594-3506', 'Logan Airport terminal C', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '2128', '42.366954', '-71.016337'),
(16158, 'BOS Terminal C Pier B', '617-634-6031', '300 Terminal C Gate C11', '', 'East Boston', 'MA', '2128', '42.366954', '-71.016337'),
(7436, 'Cambridgeside', '617-621-9507', '100 Cambridgeside Place, Suite E108', 'Suite E108', 'Cambridge', 'MA', '02141-221', '42.367158', '-71.076366'),
(75808, 'BOS - Terminal A Delta', '', 'Boston Logan International Airport', '', 'East Boston', 'MA', '2128', '42.364545', '-71.021569'),
(7550, 'Two Atlantic Avenue', '617-723-7819', '2 Atlantic Avenue', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02110-391', '42.363920', '-71.050292'),
(72417, 'BOS - Terminal B - Gates 1-3', '', 'Boston Logan International Airport, Terminal A', 'Terminal A', 'East Boston', 'MA', '2128', '42.362660', '-71.017869'),
(75534, 'BOS - Gate 25', '617-938-4567', 'Gate 25', '', 'East Boston', 'MA', '2128', '42.362418', '-71.018339'),
(7338, 'Central Square', '617-354-5471', '655 Massachussets Ave', '', 'Cambridge', 'MA', '02139-333', '42.365661', '-71.103707'),
(75649, 'BOS - Terminal B - Pier B', '617-634-6097', 'Boston Logan Term B Pier A-Tampopo', '', 'East Boston', 'MA', '2128', '42.362050', '-71.019871'),
(8742, 'Cambridge Center', '617-577-7511', '6 Cambridge Center', '', 'Cambridge', 'MA', '02142-140', '42.363719', '-71.087931'),
(72208, 'Marriott Boston Cambridge', '617-494-6600', '2 Cambridge Center', '', 'Cambridge', 'MA', '02142-160', '42.362501', '-71.084694'),
(857, 'Cambridge Street', '617-227-2959', '222 Cambridge Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02114-271', '42.361026', '-71.066486'),
(75637, 'Boston Long Wharf Marriott', '617-227-0800', '296 State St', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02109-260', '42.359776', '-71.052130'),
(862, 'Fanueil Hall', '617-227-3821', '2-4 Faneuil Hall Market Place', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02109-617', '42.359591', '-71.055841'),
(883, 'Steaming Kettle', '617-227-2284', '63-65 Court Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02108-210', '42.359465', '-71.059376'),
(9463, '84 State Street', '617-523-3053', '84 State Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02109-220', '42.359121', '-71.055600'),
(864, 'Charles Street', '617-227-3812', '97 Charles Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02114-325', '42.358883', '-71.070565'),
(875, 'Devonshire', '617-720-2220', '240 Washington St.', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02108-460', '42.357898', '-71.057821'),
(7535, '27 School Street', '617-227-7731', '27 School Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02108-463', '42.357726', '-71.059220'),
(7805, 'One International Place', '617-737-4688', '1 International Place', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02110-260', '42.356450', '-71.051818'),
(3773, 'Target Watertown T-1442', '', '550 Arsenal Street', '', 'Watertown', 'MA', '02472-285', '42.364217', '-71.156993'),
(7268, 'One Federal Bldg.', '617-357-6410', '1 Federal Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02110-201', '42.356101', '-71.056999'),
(801, 'Starbucks Boston Common', '617-742-2664', '65-66 Beacon', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '2108', '42.356349', '-71.069312'),
(7531, '12 Winter Street', '617-542-1313', '12 Winter Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02108-470', '42.355708', '-71.061027'),
(7382, 'Watertown - Mt. Auburn', '617-926-4644', '75 Mt Auburn Street', '', 'Watertown', 'MA', '02472-392', '42.366427', '-71.181086'),
(869, 'Federal Street', '617-946-0535', '75-101 Federal Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02110-190', '42.355049', '-71.057263'),
(7201, '211 Congress', '617-542-4439', '211 Congress Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02110-241', '42.354673', '-71.054837'),
(11684, 'Cambridge, Memorial Drive', '617-661-5817', '750 Memorial Drive', '', 'Cambridge', 'MA', '02139-461', '42.357962', '-71.115104'),
(10599, '125 Summer St.', '617-737-0250', '125 Summer Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02110-161', '42.353170', '-71.057619'),
(7377, 'One Financial Center-Dewey Sq.', '617-428-0019', '1 Financial Center', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02111-262', '42.352262', '-71.056024'),
(7564, '62 Boylston', '617-338-0067', '62 Boylston Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02116-479', '42.352251', '-71.064439'),
(7686, 'Brighton/Soldiers Field', '617-782-1325', '1660-1670 Soldiers Field Rd', '', 'Brighton', 'MA', '02135-111', '42.358906', '-71.153598'),
(830, '443 Boylston Street', '617-536-7177', '443 Boylston Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02116-330', '42.351504', '-71.072997'),
(807, 'City Place - Boston', '617-227-7332', '143 Stuart Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02116-560', '42.351076', '-71.065945'),
(870, '165 Newbury', '617-536-5282', '165 Newbury Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02116-287', '42.350805', '-71.078872'),
(7916, 'Saco', '207-286-3850', '509 Main Street', '', 'Saco', 'ME', '04072-156', '43.508877', '-70.434748'),
(78025, 'Boston DoubleTree', '617-956-7900', '821 Washington Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02111-151', '42.348960', '-71.064154'),
(75830, 'Renaissance Boston Harbor Lobby', '', '636 Congress St', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02210-280', '42.347946', '-71.039670'),
(7544, '755 Boylston St', '617-450-0310', '755 Boylston Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02116-261', '42.349256', '-71.080937'),
(72111, 'George Sherman Union Bldg.', '617-353-2991', '775 Commonwealth Ave.', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02215-140', '42.351153', '-71.108963'),
(75265, 'Manulife Financial', '617-663-3269', '601 Congress St', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02210-280', '42.347488', '-71.040334'),
(822, '441 Stuart Street', '617-859-0703', '441 Stuart Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02116-501', '42.348457', '-71.076293'),
(7652, 'Westin Hotel Copley', '617-867-0491', '10 Huntington Ave, Ste D', 'Ste D', 'Boston', 'MA', '02116-570', '42.348440', '-71.077587'),
(75912, 'Westin Boston Waterfront', '617-532-4600', '425 Summer St', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02210-171', '42.347100', '-71.043673'),
(10155, 'Newton Corner', '617-796-3720', '259 Centre Street', '', 'Newton', 'MA', '02458-162', '42.359008', '-71.185313'),
(70015, 'Boston University-580 Commonwealth', '617-353-5450', '580 Commonwealth Ave', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02215-252', '42.349686', '-71.100260'),
(7702, '874 Commonwealth Avenue', '617-734-3691', '874 Commonwealth Ave', '', 'Brookline', 'MA', '2215', '42.350550', '-71.114551'),
(72107, 'School of Management', '617-353-1529', '595 Commonwealth Ave', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02215-170', '42.349331', '-71.100046'),
(872, '350 Newbury', '617-859-5751', '350 Newbury Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02115-271', '42.348110', '-71.087150'),
(75513, 'Marriott Boston Copley-Mall Entrnc', '617-236-5800', '110 Huntington Ave', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02116-578', '42.346988', '-71.079236'),
(7234, 'Mass Avenue at Havland', '617-236-4335', '147-151 Massachusetts Avenue', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02115-260', '42.346806', '-71.087520'),
(72163, 'Boston Sheraton-Main Lobby', '617-378-6210', '39 Dalton Street', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02199-390', '42.346573', '-71.083844'),
(824, 'Harvard Street', '617-738-8005', '473 Harvard Street', '', 'Brookline', 'MA', '02446-243', '42.347042', '-71.128464'),
(11726, 'Fenway Triangle Trilogy', '617-867-6545', '142-148 Brookline Avenue', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02215-390', '42.344278', '-71.101407'),
(7551, 'Tremont-South End', '617-236-7879', '627 Tremont St, Retail Space #1', 'Retail Space #1', 'Boston', 'MA', '02118-164', '42.342611', '-71.074641'),
(7823, 'Brighton Village', '617-787-2430', '470 Washington St', '', 'Brighton', 'MA', '02135-267', '42.348748', '-71.159854'),
(2767, 'Huntington Plaza', '617-536-6501', '273 Huntington Ave', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02115-450', '42.342014', '-71.086182'),
(867, 'Coolidge Corner', '617-739-3453', '277 Harvard St', '', 'Brookline', 'MA', '02446-290', '42.342587', '-71.121630'),
(75363, 'Northeastern U - Curry Student Ctr', '617-373-8860', '346 Huntington Ave', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02115-500', '42.339585', '-71.089353'),
(7384, 'Newtonville', '617-965-5997', '16-18 Austin Street', '', 'Newtonville', 'MA', '02460-182', '42.350435', '-71.207591'),
(7224, 'Beth Israel', '617-277-2350', '364 Brookline Ave.', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02215-540', '42.338293', '-71.106176'),
(7804, 'Childrens'' Hospital', '617-277-5202', '283 Longwood Avenue', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02115-570', '42.337712', '-71.104718'),
(7336, 'Brookline-Washington Sq.', '617-232-5940', '1655 Beacon Street', '', 'Brookline', 'MA', '02445-450', '42.338746', '-71.136630'),
(7481, 'Brookline Village', '617-232-5063', '15 Harvard Street', '', 'Brookline', 'MA', '02445-790', '42.333719', '-71.118719'),
(16439, 'Cleveland Circle', '617-232-0119', '1948 Beacon St', '', 'Brighton', 'MA', '02135-770', '42.336080', '-71.150371'),
(76139, 'Target Dorchester T-1898', '617-602-1921', '7 Allstate Rd', '', 'Boston', 'MA', '02125-165', '42.328870', '-71.062881'),
(8741, 'Newton', '617-964-9690', '1269 Centre Street', '', 'Newton Centre', 'MA', '02459-153', '42.330258', '-71.194991'),
(811, 'Chestnut Hill', '617-738-6939', '1154-1160 Boylston Street', '', 'Chestnut Hill', 'MA', '02467-232', '42.323624', '-71.162437'),
(835, 'Waban', '617-244-0390', '474 Woodward Street', '', 'Waban', 'MA', '02468-152', '42.326420', '-71.230214'),
(7797, 'Newton Lower Falls', '617-630-9870', '2322 Washington Street', '', 'Newton', 'MA', '2462', '42.325456', '-71.256504'),
(76403, 'Target Leominster T-1965', '978-534-2914', '86 Orchard Hill Park Dr', '', 'Leominster', 'MA', '01453-702', '42.527313', '-71.713782'),
(880, 'South Brookline', '617-325-6261', '183 Grove St', '', 'South Brookline', 'MA', '2467', '42.303253', '-71.152063'),
(7270, 'Newton Upper Falls', '617-332-8839', '244 Needham Street', '', 'Newton', 'MA', '2464', '42.309391', '-71.213785'),
(8956, 'Leominster, Commercial Road', '978-840-1670', '14 Commercial Rd', '', 'Leominster', 'MA', '01453-333', '42.535070', '-71.741658'),
(7301, 'Sudbury', '978-579-9977', '513 Boston Post Road', '', 'Sudbury', 'MA', '01776-331', '42.359303', '-71.430362'),
(7808, 'West Roxbury- Roche Bros.', '617-325-4717', '1810 Centre Street', '', 'West Roxbury', 'MA', '02132-190', '42.287204', '-71.152575'),
(6849, 'Crenshaw & Airport, Torrance', '310-534-4835', '25348 Crenshaw Blvd.', '', 'Torrance', 'CA', '90505-610', '33.792659', '-118.331678'),
(75545, 'Warner Brothers Studio', '818-977-3460', '4000 Warner Blvd', '', 'Burbank', 'CA', '91522-000', '34.150500', '-118.340065');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: This would be much easier to help answer if you could provide code snippets and any errors your browers development console.

Comment: There are no errors - it just doesn't work.  I'll add a copy of the code directly (it's quite long so I thought that would be annoying)

Comment: Why don't you debug the JS code to see what happens in the AJAX callback?

Comment: And there is no `Visits` field in your table.

Comment: @Olivier thanks for info on how to proceed.  I can see now that it cannot load the coffee.php file - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://127.0.0.1/coffeeExample/coffee.php. Wrong path to the file is the most likely answer I can find - however the html file and coffee.php are both in the same parent folder (coffeeExample) /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/coffeeExample/

Comment: @Olivier I removed all reference to visits - sadly that doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right.

I tried running this in an apache docker-container, and a mysql db in another docker-container. I got a couple of suggestions as to the possible errors. Although I believe suggestion 2-4 are the most likely to help you.

1. The link you use for importing JQuery seems to be dated. Instead of:

```html
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Try:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

2. Make sure that `coffee.php` connects correctly with the database. You can do this by looking directly at the PHP-output (http://localhost/coffee.php). I had an issue with the uppercase-letters in the sql on line 3 of `coffee.php`. While MySQL is case insensitive with regards to table-names, I believe PHP's `$db->query();` is. Regardless I would stay away from uppercase table names.
   For me I just did:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM coffeeshops WHERE City='Boston'";
```

3. The last thing I would recommend you to check is the JSON-encoding and -decoding. `json_decode();`, tend not to throw errors when fed incorrectly formated JSON.
4. Make sure that the `getJSON` function actually returns the correct JSON. I used `http://localhost/coffee.php` as the endpoint for the getJSON request, instead of just `coffee.php`.

---

If none of these help you, then please provide us with the returned output of the `coffee.php` file and with a `console.log();` of the data that was fetched by the `getJSON`.

This is the output I got (I had to add my own mug.png file):
[Screenshot of output on listing43.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FmoV.jpg)

Comment: Both of the URLs you provided for the jQuery CDN are the same.

Comment: @Riverans - 3 was an issue - coffee.php on localhost was blank.  I fixed that issue (password wasn't set up correctly) + changed capitalisation - and now it's returning the database entries.  Working through others ...

Comment: @Riverans - the final part of the fix (I did steps 2 and 4 already) was adding CORS access to the php file (that error popped up when I fixed the password call).  I added ` header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ` to the coffee.php file on line 2 (immediately before the $db line). Thanks - multiple errors are rather hard to debug as a newbie

Comment: @Esme_ Glad it helpt. :)